How do I source zsh theme and show the results and move the next theme?
To load a theme called theme-name in zsh shell you do
source ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/theme-name.zsh-theme

I want to loop through the themes in ~/oh-my-zsh/themes/ and source each one and see how it looks like in the terminal and then move on to the next one.
I did a simple for loop like so but it gets stuck somewhere (like infinite loop, I am not sure but I hit Ctrl-C before it terminates):
for f in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/*.zsh-theme; do source $f; sleep 5; done

If I remove the sleep 5 command, it does not get stuck but only loads the same theme every time.

Do not tag both bash and zsh in the same question. One shell, or the other; bash should not be tagged on a zsh question.

That said, how would you get to see how something looks in the terminal if you aren't printing a prompt? (When you run a for loop, no prompt is printed until the entire loop finishes -- as such, nothing's "getting stuck", the shell is just running sleep commands like you told it to).

Did you know the oh-my-zsh website includes screenshots of the themes? Why are you doing this again?

Your current code doesn't work because you can't see what a theme looks like until your shell actually prints a prompt, and when you run a loop in the shell, it doesn't print any prompts until the entire loop is finished.
Consider using a precmd hook to change themes every time a new prompt is printed:
themes=( ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/*.zsh-theme )
precmd() {
  if (( ${#themes[@]} )); then
    echo "--- Switching theme to ${themes[0]}" >&2
    source "${themes[0]}"
    themes=( "${themes[@]:1}" )
    shift
  else
    echo "!!! No remaining themes" >&2
    unset -f precmd
  fi
}

This will switch themes every time you press enter to print a new prompt.
